# Unable resolve dependency for MPandroidChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I'm working on Android project where I'm trying to add MPAndroidChart as follows,

At project level build.gradle file I've two repositories,

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
  }
}
```

Gradle 'Sync' at this point worked okay. After that I added following line to the app/build.gradle file as,

```
dependencies {
  ...
  ...
  ...
  implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'
}
```

With this change, I started getting 'Could not resolve' error shown below,
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.github.PhilJay:MPandroidChart:v3.0.3.

What am I missing? Any help is appreciated.

Build env:
Mac OS X High Sierra, 10.13
Android Studio version: 3.1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Project)build.gradle

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
```

}

(app)build.gradle
dependency

```
implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

Please add below code in gradle file:

```
repositories {
jcenter()
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

 }



dependencies {

implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.4'
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, i added the code you post, but mine works well...
AndroidStudio 3.1 Beta2, macOS High Sierra Version 10.13.4.
So check your code again, or blame your AS...